# How to cover this part in test class

Tags: unit-test

Apex Class:

```
public PageReference Save()
{
    service.Asset_Name__c =assetname;
    insert service;

   Task T = new Task();
        T.WhatId=assetname;
        T.WhoId=service.Employee__c;
        T.OwnerId= UserInfo.getUserId();

        insert T;

    PageReference ref= new PageReference('/'+assetname);
    ref.setredirect(true);
    return ref;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to use a name field instead of an ID field as a return URL for the standard cotnroller. The controller in turn is trying to turn that name into an Id, and as the error states, 'PhysicalAssetName' is not a valid Salesforce ID.

```
ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().put('retURL','/'+phy.Name);
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(testservice);
```

Swap the name for the Id and you should be good:

```
ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().put('retURL','/'+phy.Id);
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(testservice);
```